# Get method receiver with reflect

Tags: go

Is it possible to find the receiver if any of a method using reflect?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
)

type F func(v string) error

type S struct {
}

func (s S) Func(v string) error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    f := S{}.Func
    doSomething(f)
}

func doSomething(f F) {
    //get the receiver of `f`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gkgba_XkZi_P

Comment: Nope, it is not.

Comment: The receiver is just a function argument. You _can_ learn what type of argument that is via reflection, but the receiver, per se, doesn't exist at that level, so there's nothing to "get" anyway.

Comment: @Flimzy but not with a "method value" (`S{}.F`) as in the question right? If OP used a "method expression" (`S.F`) instead then sure, they would be able to retrieve the receiver's type by inspecting the first argument but then the result of that expression would not match the `F` func type anymore, so they wouldn't be able to pass it to `doSomething`.

Comment: You can access the type and method name (something like `S.Func`), but not the actual `S` receiver value. To get the type and method name: `runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(f).Pointer()).Name()`

Comment: In addition to the above comments: If you have an actual, real-world scenario you need help with (as opposed to simple academic curiosity), it would be good to explain that problem. There may be some other solution. Don't fall into the XY Problem trap :)